# SDL2 - как перемещать окно без заголовка

Tags: c++, c, sdl2

Как правильно в SDL2 перемещать окно без заголовка, по аналогии с winapi используя `WM_NCHITTEST`.

Видел примеры где как то с боку прикручивают WinProc(), но это как то делать не хочется. Какой родной способ носить окно мышью кликнув и удерживая клавишу мыши на клиентской области для SDL2? Окно не OpenGL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого есть [`SDL_SetWindowHitTest`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowHitTest).

В него передается колбэк, который по координатам пикселя должен говорить, можно ли за этот пиксель перетаскивать окно или растягивать его в конкретную сторону.